Specifying a Conditional (Switch) field in Python Construct that depends on a look-ahead value
I'm building a parser for a (slightly bizzare) format that defines the tag of a data field after the value record. It is guaranteed that the value field would always be 4 bytes interpreted depending on the tag.
This code works (but is cumbersome to use, and requires manually switching to the correct field of an Union):
SC_Header = Int32ul
SC_Object = Int32ul 
SC_String = BitStruct (
    "latin1" / Flag, 
    "buffer" / Flag, 
    "length" / BitsInteger(30) 
)

SC_Pair = Struct (
    "value" / Union(0, 
        "header" / SC_Header,
        "object" / SC_Object,
        "string" / SC_String,
    ),
    "tag" / Int32ul, 
)

This declares fine, but fails when used:
SC_Header = Int32ul
SC_Object = Int32ul 
SC_String = BitStruct (
    "latin1" / Flag, 
    "buffer" / Flag, 
    "length" / BitsInteger(30) 
)

SC_Pair = Struct (
    "value" / Switch(lambda ctx: ctx.tag, {
        0xFFF10000: SC_Header, 
        0xFFFF0008: SC_Object,
        0xFFFF0004: SC_String, 
    }),
    "tag" / Int32ul, 
)

Even though it works (for a fictitious format) in which value follows tag. In my case, I need to look-ahead for the tag, before it's fed into the context.
How can I specify the field to achieve that?

What is your question?

Maybe post the part of your parser you are struggling with, and some sample inputs that aren't nice to parse.

@mkrieger1 - how do I specify, well, what I need (the look-ahead field?)..
